# How to add a new line to a string variable using Javascript/Typescript in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to add a new line to a string in Angular application. In component.ts file I have added a variable which takes a string value.

```
heading="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \n consetetur sadipscing elitr."
```

In component.html file I am calling this variable.

```
<div>{{heading}}</div>
```

But no new line is generated and the text is one single paragraph. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: In HTML a newline is achieved with a <br>

Comment: in HTML template use innerHTML binding... <h1 [innerHTML]="heading"></h1> and in component use... heading="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <br> consetetur sadipscing elitr."

Answer (score 2):

Try to add CSS style to to that Div.

```
div{
white-space:pre-line;
}
```

It should render \n in the browser.